# MVC - nothing happens on click (Jquery in view)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want my button to do something `onClick()`, it has the ID `btnSend`. But nothing happens when I click the button which is weird and I can't figure out why.

- The script is in my view for now within script tags.

  ```
  $("#btnSend").click(function () {


      var messageInfo = {
          "Body": $("#Message").val(),

      };

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/Api/Posts',
          data: JSON.stringify(messageInfo),
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          processData: true,
          success: function (data, status, xhr) {
              alert("The result is : " + status);
          },
          error: function (xhr) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: First make sure that your click event fires (using alert,console.log,debugger, or something).

Comment: Is this code in document.Ready()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your script is running after the page is loaded?

Put your script at the bottom of the page and give it a try.